# Prove that a surface is a conical surface

Tags: differential-geometry

The question follows that

> If the tangent plane of a surface passes a fixed point, then it is a conical surface.(i.e. it can be parametrically represented as $\vec{r}(u,v)=\vec{a}+v\vec{b}(u)$. where $\vec{a}$ is constant vector).

I have the following attempt:

It is known that $\langle \vec{r}-\vec{a},\vec{n}\rangle=0$ by the assumption, where $\vec{a}$ is constant vector, $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector. Sowe get
$$\langle \vec{r}-\vec{a},\vec{n_u}\rangle=\langle \vec{r}-\vec{a},\vec{n_v}\rangle=0.$$
Then one of $\vec{n_u},\vec{n_v}$ must be equal to zero. WLOG $\vec{n_v}=0$,we may assume $\vec{n}=\vec{f}(u)$. Also, this imples $\vec{r}_v=\alpha(u,v)(\vec{r}-\vec{a})$ since $\vec{r}_v $ is perpendicular to both $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{n}_u$.

But how to proceed this proof? I have been thinking if this for a long time. Thanks for you helping hand.

Comment: I'm not sure how you deduced that one of $\vec n_u$ and $\vec n_v$ must equal $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Otherwise, by the inverse Weingarten transform, both $r_u$ and $r_v$ must be parallel, which gives a contradiction I think.

Comment: I don't follow this. Just because $n_u$ and $n_v$ are parallel, we cannot conclude that one must be $0$. If your parametrization does not have the lines being $u$-curves or $v$-curves, your statement will be false.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, I have seen your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch for you to fill in:

Since $\vec n$, $\vec n_u$, and $\vec n_v$ are linearly dependent and the latter two are orthogonal to the first, we conclude that $\vec n_u$ and $\vec n_v$ are linearly dependent. In particular, the Gauss map has rank at most $1$. Assuming it is $1$, choose a parametrization so that the $n_v=0$. It now follows from the Mainardi-Codazzi equations that the $v$-curves are lines, so that the surface is a ruled surface. Last, parametrizing the surface as a ruled surface $x(u,v) = \alpha(u) + v\beta(u)$, it follows that $\alpha'$, $\beta$, and $\beta'$ are everywhere linearly dependent. Now you should be able to use the fact that all the tangent planes have a common point to show that $\alpha + \lambda\beta=\text{constant}$ for some function $\lambda=\lambda(u)$.

**EDIT:** Here's the easiest way to finish it up. Parametrize so that the $v$-curves are the rulings and the $u$-curves are the orthogonal trajectories (therefore also lines of curvature, so $n_u = kx_u$, where $k\ne 0$. Assuming the tangent planes all pass through the origin, we have $n\cdot x=0$, and so $n_u\cdot x = 0$, whence $x_u\cdot x =0$. It follows that $x=\lambda x_v=\lambda\beta$ for some scalar function $\lambda$. This tells us that our surface is a cone.

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit confused with "from the Mainardi-Codazzi equations that the $v$-curves are lines", why is this true? Sorry for my silly question.

Comment: See, for example, Lemma 3.3 and Proposition 3.4 in my [notes](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: So it follows that $\alpha',\beta,\beta'$ are linear dependent because $v$ is arbitrary and they are all on the tangent space? And then I can conclude that $\alpha(u)+\left(\gamma_1(\alpha'(u)+v\beta'(u))+\gamma_2 \beta(u)\right)= P_0$ and the latter one can be represented by $\beta$ and $\beta'$. But this cannot give a $\lambda$ depends only on $u$. Also, I don't know how to eliminate $\beta'$. Should another parametrization be applied? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Golbez: See my edit.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.